# will top margin and text align work for display-inline-block

Tags: html, css, block, inline, display

I know both the left and right margins will work for `display: inline` and `display-inline: block`. But please clarify if `top margin` and `text-align` works for any of these. If yes, why?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers treat inline elements differently when it comes to margins and padding. While you can add left and right margins/padding, you can not add them to the top or bottom of the element. This is because inline elements flow with the content on a page, the same way as a link or text. If you were able to set top/bottom margin/padding in inline elements, it would disrupt the flow of content.

As for text-align, this works on both `inline-block`, and `inline` elements. I have added a quick code example below showing `text-align: center;` on both `display: inline;` and `display: inline-block;` elements. This example also shows the top and bottom margins working for inline-block, and not working for inline.

```css
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.inline {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Start demo styles (not required) */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body {
  margin:0;
  background: #95a5a6;
}
.container {
  width:50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}
hr {
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: block;
}
/* End demo styles */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inline-block">
    Inline-Block Content
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="inline">
    Inline Content
  </div>
</div>
```